# Gulp: Copy files to destination, then alter files, all in one task?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Using `gulp` I intend to do the following:

1. Copy a directory of files (that include JavaScript files, images, and CSS) to a destination directory.
2. After copying is complete, do some operations on JUST the JavaScript files.

My first thought was to simply use the `gulp-ignore` plugin like so:

```
gulp.src('./mydirectory')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./targetdirectory'))
  .pipe(gulpIgnore.include('./targetdirectory/**/*.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./targetdirectory'));
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Is it not possible to pipe anything after a `gulp.dest()`?

I could obviously split this up into two tasks: The first one copies and the second one does `uglify()`. But can this be done in a single task?

Comment: Typically I'd say it's best to make a task per logical unit of function (one for copy and one for operation on js here). Then, make a task which calls the two of these (or make the js operation one dependent on the previous one).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

https://github.com/klaascuvelier/gulp-copy

gulp.dest does end your task, but you can perform more tasks after doing the copy. Then at the end, clean up the original directory.